# How can I use Theano with GPU on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, theano, theano-cuda

I use the following script to test if GPU is working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from theano import function, config, shared, sandbox
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy
import time

vlen = 10 * 30 * 768  # 10 x #cores x # threads per core
iters = 1000

rng = numpy.random.RandomState(22)
x = shared(numpy.asarray(rng.rand(vlen), config.floatX))
f = function([], T.exp(x))
print f.maker.fgraph.toposort()
t0 = time.time()
for i in xrange(iters):
    r = f()
t1 = time.time()
print 'Looping %d times took' % iters, t1 - t0, 'seconds'
print 'Result is', r
if numpy.any([isinstance(x.op, T.Elemwise) for x in f.maker.fgraph.toposort()]):
    print('Used the cpu')
else:
    print('Used the gpu')
```

When I run it, I get:

http://pastebin.com/wM9jaGMF

The interesting part is at the end:

```
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: ('nvcc return status', 1, 'for cmd', 'nvcc -shared -O3 -m64 -Xcompiler -DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=c72d035fdf91890f3b36710688069b2e,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,-fPIC,-fvisibility=hidden -Xlinker -rpath,/home/moose/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.4--generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial-x86_64-2.7.11+-64/cuda_ndarray -I/home/moose/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/home/moose/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof -o /home/moose/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.4--generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial-x86_64-2.7.11+-64/cuda_ndarray/cuda_ndarray.so mod.cu -L/usr/lib -lcublas -lpython2.7 -lcudart')
WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu is not available  (error: cuda unavailable)
```

### My system

- I use Ubuntu 16.04.
- I've installed CUDA through the standard repos (`V7.5.17`). `nvcc --version` works.
- I've installed Theano via pip
- I have CuDNN 4 (works with TensorFlow)
- I set `CUDA_ROOT=/usr/bin/` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` (I'm not sure if that is correct)

My `~/.theanorc` is

```
[global]
exception_verbosity=high
device=gpu
floatX=float32

[cuda]
root=/usr/bin/
```

### Paths

I think the installation from the standard repos might make things different from a manual installation. Here are some paths which might uncover some problems:

```
/usr/bin/nvcc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so
/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit
/usr/include/cudnn.h
```

### Question

How can I make it work?

Comment: One possible approach: read [the CUDA installation guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#abstract), and follow it carefully, including the verification steps contained in it, before moving on to theano.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Yes, I know. But I do have a working CUDA installation (I know it is working, because it does with TensorFlow). I would really want to avaid installing it manually and probably not getting it to work for both, Theano and TensorFlow after that

Comment: OK great, then it's just a theano setup issue.  Because the "verification" steps you listed (e.g. `nvcc --version`) don't verify much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what solved the issue, but one or both of the following ([source](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_ubuntu.html))

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-dev python-pip python-nose g++ libopenblas-dev libblas-dev git
echo -e "\n[nvcc]\nflags=-D_FORCE_INLINES\n" >> ~/.theanorc
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a more general answer here in case others find themselves in a similar situation.
First, see that theano dependencies are installed, as explained [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_ubuntu.html). you should install nvidia driver as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia), use `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` to determine which driver is recommended and install it with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-xxx` (xxx = 375 at this time). Then see that the nvidia driver is being used by opening "additional drivers" window (from terminal `software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4`). Setup a ~/.theanorc text file as follows:

```
[global]
exception_verbosity=high
device=gpu
floatX=float32

[cuda]
root=/usr/bin/

[nvcc]
flags=-D_FORCE_INLINES

[lib]
cnmem = 1
```

[lib] section is not necessary but on my laptop performance was about 2 times faster when adding it to .theanorc.

Comment: This seems not providing an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).